# How to continue data writing on a new pdf page if it exceeds the page size in iTextShartp pdf

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext

I have gone through this site but could not find the relative solution to my problem.

Here is my problem
 I am creating a PDF file using iTextSharp and the file is being created very well. I am creating a table and assigning it a gridview data as follows.

```
//Add Actual columns from the datatable
for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++) {
    PdfPCell cellHeader = new PdfPCell(FormatHeaderPhrase(dt.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToString()));
    cellHeader.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
    table3.AddCell(cellHeader);// adds the header with proeprties
}
//Add the actual rows from the datatable
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < dt.Columns.Count; k++) {
        PdfPCell cellRows = new PdfPCell(FormatPhrase(dt.Rows[i][k].ToString().Replace("<br/>","\n").Replace("<sup>","")));
        if (k != 2) {
            cellRows.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            cellRows.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
        }
        else {
            cellRows.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
        }
        table3.AddCell(cellRows);
        table3.SplitRows = true;
        table3.SplitLate = true;
    }
}
```

I have a A3 page size. The concern here is, when my data in the table exceeds  the page size, it trims the exceeded part and just shows the data which fits in one page. How to make it multipage(auto page break) based on the content of the table. Currently I am seeing the data which fits into one page of pdf. It should have generated more than one pages. How can I achieve this.

Please let me know your inputs. I would appreciate them. Thank you.

Comment: From the documentation: "By default, iText only splits rows that are forwarded to the next page but that still don't fit because the row height exceeds the available page height." There's an example that proves that when a table doesn't fit, a new page is created automatically. In other words: the documentation claims the exact opposite of what you're saying. I tend to believe the documentation because I've written and tested those examples myself. Try the following examples to convince yourself that what the documentation says is correct: http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C04

Comment: I am reading the doc.I am wondering how is this behavior achieved in the iTextSharp Examples. In this example, the content is broken on new page on its own.I want to do exactly this.http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part1/chapter05/movie_history2.pdf  Could you please throw some light on it.

Comment: I'm as amazed as you are. Have you tried my examples? They work don't they? Unfortunately, I can't try your examples as you don't provide a http://sscce.org/

Comment: Hey, I found the solution. I think my understanding was different. I will explain what I did so that this might help some one like me in the future. When you do doc.Add(), this will add after the last added element and does the page break according to content size whereas WriteSelectedRows() adds the element to the specific mentioned position but does not break the page based on content size. So I had used both doc.add and WriteSelectedRows() to organize elements on my page. And this works like a charm now. Hope this helps someone. Thank you  Bruno and testuser for your help. I appreciate them

Comment: Aha, that was the part missing in the code in your question. Most people use document.Add().

Answer (score 0):

This may work, try creating new page after every n rows, suppose if current page fits only 
10 rows, creating new page after every 10th record

Suppose you created a initial document instance

`Document document =new Document(PageSize.A4);`

After n rows, add new page by calling

```
document.NewPage();
```

Comment: I think, my question should be how to use the page break in iTextsharp. Is there anyway to let Itextsharp do page break on its own by considering the size of the page and content. I tried your solution but what it is doing is just pushing the entire table on the new page, instead of splitting the table according to the available page size. Is there any trick to achieve this?